# Java spring distributed lock with redis: different lock timeout for each lock

Tags: java, spring, redis

I need to create locks for each task execution, however different tasks can have differents locks timeout. I'm using Spring distributed lock with Redis, there's a snippet of my example code:

```
@Override
public boolean lock(String taskKey) {
    if(taskKey == null || taskKey.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key must be not null!");
    }
    Lock lock = lockRegistry.obtain(taskKey);

try{
    if(!lock.tryLock()){
        logger.warn("Unable to lock resource {}", taskKey);
        return false;
    }

    logger.debug("Resource {} locked ", taskKey);
    return true;
}catch(Exception exc){
    throw exc;
}
```

}

and what I want is to set differents lock timeout for each taskKey. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException;
```

As you can see, method tryLock optionally takes 2 arguments.

```
if(!lock.tryLock(30, SECONDS)){
  logger.warn("Unable to lock resource {}", taskKey);
  return false;
}
```